# jquery returning null - why?

Tags: jquery, find

I am using jquery ajax $.get which calls a php script on my server and retrieves content from another site (domain). It return's the full web page ok. I then want to extract html data from the 'center' tag using the .find() method, but I am having some issues.

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function(){
  $.get("pgiproxy.php",{ data: $("#formdata").serialize() },
    function(result) {

      alert($(result).find('center').html()); 

      val = $(result).find('center').html();
      alert(val);

      $('#BFX').html(result);
      alert( $('#BFX').find('center').html() );  

    });
});
```

The first 2 methods both return 'null', but when I insert the ('result') html into the #BFX div it displays correctly on my monitor, the final alert works correctly, it find()s the 'center' tag and displays the html data in the alert.

Can anybody see why I get 'null' returned (as in the first 2 alerts) when trying to 'find()' the 'center' tag from the returned ajax data 'result'.

Any help is appreciated

Nic.

Comment: I'm not used to jquery, but `result.find('center').html()` should not work?

Comment: did you dump the contents of 'result' ? you may try to set the datatype after your callback to 'html'    $.get('foo', {}, function(){}, 'html');

Comment: Hi jAndy, I set the datatype to 'html', still the same result using -- alert($(result).find('center').html()); --, returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this:

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function(){
  $.get("pgiproxy.php",{ data: $("#formdata").serialize() },
    function(result) {
      var temp = $('<div/>').html(result);

      alert(temp.find('center').html()); 

      val = temp.find('center').html();
      alert(val);

      $('#BFX').html(result);
      alert( $('#BFX').find('center').html() );  

    });
});
```

Comment: hi vsnyc, yes this method worked. But why do I need to put the data into the 'temp' variable first before I 'find('center').html()'. Why cant I just do a 1 step method and extract 'center' directly from 'result'??? Nic.

Comment: Because jQuery needs to traverse a DOM object or jQuery object, not a JSON object, or whatever the response it..which I take it, is not DOM one. this is the approach when doing these things, to convert the response to an element we can work on.

Comment: ok thanks vsync. The response comes from a PHP script which uses 'fopen and fgets' to grab the contents of a web page, which is returned as just 'text' I assume?.

Is $('<div/>') in "" var temp = $('<div/>').html(result); "" just used as a placeholder to convert the 'result' to a usable jQuery object?

Comment: yes, it's just a placeholder, it's not an element which is really in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `result` here are going to depend on the MIME type of the response, as mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). If `result` is just text, the `$()` function is going to treat it as a selector.

Comment: hi Syntactic, this is the code used in my php script which return the result for jquery ajax call:

function getPage($pageURL) {
  // Set your return content type
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  
  // Get that website's content
  $handle = fopen($pageURL, "r");
  
  if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
      echo $buffer;
    }
  fclose($handle);
  }
}

I assume the result is just text??? I am happy to put the result into a hidden div then extract the data from the 'center' tag, but it would be nice to do it directly.